# tickFormat is concatenated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For my axis I have the following `tickFormat`

```
.tickFormat(data.map(function (d) {
    if(ChartJourney.group_by == 'weeks') {
        console.log(moment(d.date).format('YYYY-WW'));
        return moment(d.date).format('YYYY-WW');
    } else
        return d.date;
}));
```

In the console I see this:

```
2015-23
2015-24
2015-25
2015-26
```

But on the chart I see 4 ticks all with same format like:

`2015-23,2015-24,2015-25,2015-26`

Why is the format being comma separated like that for each tick? Especially when from the console I only see it looped 4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do I need to remove the map as per @Marcelo's post, but also it should just be `d` instead of `d.date`:

```
.tickFormat(function (d) {
    if(ChartJourney.group_by == 'weeks') {
        console.log(moment(d).format('YYYY-WW'));
        return moment(d).format('YYYY-WW');
    } else
        return d;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the data.map:

```
.tickFormat(function (d) {
    if(ChartJourney.group_by == 'weeks') {
        console.log(moment(d.date).format('YYYY-WW'));
        return moment(d.date).format('YYYY-WW');
    } else
        return d.date;
});
```

the .tickFormat can accept a function or an object. When you use a function, the function will be called for each data point. This is what you want. If you do not use a function the value will be used for every tick. When you use a data.map, the map will evaluated right away. You will be calling the .tickFormat with the mapped array(not a function) which will be used for every tick.

Comment: But what is `d`? As `data` is where my data is... so removing it means that `d.date` will now return undefined. Even if I replaced `d` with `data` it will still be undefined as we're not looping through it like with the `map`.

Comment: Ah. Turns out it should just be `d` and not `d.date`.